# Image Colors Appear Wrong on Chrome/Windows

Tags: browser, colors, cross-browser

While testing a design for a site, I took a screenshot with "TinyGrab" and sent it to a friend.

The friend saw something *entirely* different from myself... On Windows and only with Chrome, the blue in this photo appears purple. On OS X (even with Chrome) or with any other browser, the blues appear just fine.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

This is the image: http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/fc3572c4aff9588ff9add4e2aad47755.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds/looks like the colour profile for your monitor or a monitor is being embedded in the file. You could try using something like [ImageOptim](http://pornel.net/imageoptim/en) (MacOSX) as part of its lossless compression removes extraneous data like profiles from images.

Hope that helps.

Comment: TinyGrab embeds your monitor profile in the picture. Chrome is the only one that uses that for rendering the PNGs.